# Rails 6 + webpack + turbolinks : not working at first page load

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, turbolinks

I'm trying to understand how to properly init a JS lib in Rails 6 with turbolinks.

For example I got this in my webpack JS file (not application.js but another one I load with a `pack_tag`):

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.carousel').slick();
   AOS.init();
   startFlexImages();
}
```

Slick is properly loaded everytime, but the other libs are not.
Though I noticed that if I navigate through the website and come back to the page, they init properly, like if they were initialized after page is fully loaded

Found this topic about it : https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/534
But I do not understand the answer of the guy that closed the topic, if somebody could explain me ?

Thank you

Comment: How are you loading your JS file? Does it have an `async` attribute?

Comment: Hi,
Not using `async` attribute.

Loading the JS in the common way :
`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'site', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', rel: 'preload' %>` in my layout

and having the js file in `app/javascript/packs/site.js`

Comment: @SimonMo did you get to any solution here?

Comment: @TalhaMeh, more or less, I used few different events, that doesn't solve exactly the problem with the fact `turbolinks:load` does not work as expected, but I could have my JS initializing.

Using `document.addEventListener("turbolinks:render", function()` that executes the JS after the page is rendered

Also using `document.addEventListener("load", function()` and kept `document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function()` too.

So at the end I use 3 events listeners, each of them calling or not the same functions, depending if I had them working or not

any better idea?